# Emulador sale de la aplicacion cuando intento guardar datos | Shared Preferences | KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

Estoy practicando con las Shared references y cree una pequeña app que guarda tu nombre y edad y lo muestra en un Text View con string concatenation el problema está que cuando intento ingresar los datos desde el emulador y le doy al boton que activa el metodo para guardar, el emulador se lsae inmediatamente de la app y no me guarda los datos, relamente no sé que ha salido mal ya que Android studio no me da ningun error, les adjunto el codigo.

```kotlin
package com.gabrielmilito.appclass.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import com.gabrielmilito.appclass.R
import com.gabrielmilito.appclass.app.preferences
import com.gabrielmilito.appclass.others.ToolbarActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_shared_references.*

class SharedReferencesActivity : ToolbarActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_references)

        toolbarToLoad(toolbar as Toolbar)
        enableHomeDisplay(true)

        buttonSave.setOnClickListener { setValuesSharedPreferences(); cleanEditTexts() }
        getValuesSharedPreferences()
    }
    fun getValuesSharedPreferences() {
        if (preferences.name!!.isNotEmpty() && preferences.age >= 0) {
            textViewSharedPreferences.text =  "Bienvenido ${preferences.name}, tu edad es ${preferences.age}."
        } else {
            textViewSharedPreferences.text = "Bienvenido, por favor guarda tu nombre y tu edad."
        }
    }

    fun setValuesSharedPreferences() {
        if (editTextName.text.toString().isNotEmpty() && editTextAge.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
            preferences.name = editTextName.text.toString()
            preferences.age = editTextName.text.toString().toInt()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Los datos se han guardado exitosamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor llena las dos casillas antes de guardar los datos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    fun cleanEditTexts() {
        editTextName.text.clear()
        editTextAge.text.clear()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
package com.gabrielmilito.appclass.app

import android.app.Application
import com.gabrielmilito.appclass.others.MySharedPreferences

val preferences: MySharedPreferences by lazy { MyApp.prefs!! }
class MyApp: Application() {
    companion object {
        var prefs: MySharedPreferences?= null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        prefs = MySharedPreferences(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
package com.gabrielmilito.appclass.others

import android.content.Context

class MySharedPreferences(context: Context) {

    // Nombre fichero del preference
    private val fileName = "mis_preferencias"
    // Instacia de ese fichero
    private val prefs  = context.getSharedPreferences(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    // Por cada una de las variables vamos a  guardar en nuestro fichero shared preferences

    var name: String?
        get() = prefs.getString("name", "")
        set(value) = prefs.edit().putString("name", value).apply()

    var age: Int
        get() = prefs.getInt("age", -1)
        set(value) = prefs.edit().putInt("age", value).apply()
}
```

ya intente haciendo un Clean/Rebuild pero no me funciono
(Todavia soy un novato)

Comment: Probablemente estás obteniendo un ClassCastException en la siguiente linea "preferences.age = editTextName.text.toString().toInt()" porque estás tratando de convertir un nombre a entero

Comment: Lo importante es revisar el LogCat y agregar en tu pregunta que error se produce para tener una solucion rapida.